# How to style webpage with percentages

Tags: html, css

Following is my page structure

```
<div class="webpage">
    <div class="image"><img...></div>
    <div class="text1"></div> <div class="text2"></div>
</div>
```

What I want is for my `webpage` to be centrally aligned. That is it should fill all the page in vertical position. But horizontally, it should cover the central 80%.

so I wrote

```
.webpage{
margin-left : 10%;
margin-right : 10%;
width : 80%;
}
```

Now, I want my image to cover the top 20% of the area, and for my text 1 and text2 to cover the rest of the bottom 80%, but they should be aligned next to each other. Not vertically, but horizontally. 
So horizontally I want 50% for text1, and 50 for text 2.

I am not sure how to style it with css.

Can someone please advice

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/tjsoL8dm/

`image` is added as `background`.

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

```css
.content {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: orange;
}
.top {
    height: 20%;
    max-height: 20%;
    background-image: url('http://sumxwaresolutions.site11.com/welcome/Tree-of-Life-Website-Banner.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
}
.bottom {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.text1 {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    word-break: break-all;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.text2 {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    word-break: break-all;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="bottom">
        <h2>bottom area</h2>
        <div class="text1">text1text1text1text1text1text1text1text1text1text1text1text1text1text1text1text1</div>
        <div class="text2">text2text2text2text2text2text2text2text2text2text2text2text2text2text2text2text2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```